# Transform string into operation

Tags: javascript, string, transform, operation

I need to transform a string like `"5+4+8*6(4)"` as an operation, after it, I will be able to calculate it (here 5+4+8*6(4) = 201)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use the mathjs library http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html

```
var result = math.eval('5+4+8*6(4)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval function:

```
eval("5+4+8*6(4)")
```

eval function have a security problem.

If you don't want to use eval you will have to use an existing expression evaluator library:

http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/

Answer (score -1):

```
var equation = 5+4+8*6(4);
alert(eval(equation));
```

Comment: Yes but how do you transform "5+4+8*6(4)" to 5+4+8*6(4) ?